# How to compare multiple rows in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following values:

```
    Time        IP           Message
0   12:00.00    192.168.1.1  Link up
1   12:01.00    192.168.1.1  Link Down
2   12:01.40    192.168.1.2  Link up
3   12:01.60    192.168.1.1  Link up
```

I would like to identify when a particular IP gives the messages "Link up", "Link down" and "link up" again, in under 5 minutes

Comment: Please copy and paste your dataframe, don't show images. We need it to help you:)

Comment: We love users who show their effort in solving the problem.

Comment: You are welcome. tell me if my solutino works:)

Answer (score 0):

**Preparing**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Time':['12:00.0','12:01.0','12:01.4','12:01.6'],
                 'IP':'192.168.1.1 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1'.split(),
                  'Message':['Link up','Link down','Link up','Link up']})
```

---

Converting to datetime using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) 
to be able to calculate the differences

```
df2=df.copy()
df2['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df2['Time'])
print(df2)

                 Time           IP    Message
0 2019-11-04 12:00:00  192.168.1.1    Link up
1 2019-11-04 12:01:00  192.168.1.1  Link down
2 2019-11-04 12:01:24  192.168.1.2    Link up
3 2019-11-04 12:01:36  192.168.1.1    Link up
```

---

Now we group in 5 minute intervals using [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) and depending on the IP address, for this we use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).
we assign 1 1 1 to the pattern values ​​when it occurs in less than 5 minutes. You could also have established any other critic.

```
group_5_min=pd.Grouper(key='Time',freq='5m')
val='Link up'
df['secuence_under_five']=( df2.groupby([group_5_min,'IP'],sort=False)
                               .Message
                               .transform(lambda x:(x.eq(val)&x.shift(-1).ne(val)&x.shift(-2).eq(val)).cumsum() )
print(df)
```

---

```
      Time           IP    Message  secuence_under_five
0  12:00.0  192.168.1.1    Link up                    1
1  12:01.0  192.168.1.1  Link down                    1
2  12:01.4  192.168.1.2    Link up                    0
3  12:01.6  192.168.1.1    Link up                    1
```

---

If your prefer you could set to 1 only the first value of the secuence. You only need remove [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) method:

```
df['secuence_under_five']=( df2.groupby([group_5_min,'IP'],sort=False)
                               .Message
                               .transform(lambda x:(x.eq(val)&x.shift(-1).ne(val)&x.shift(-2).eq(val)) )
print(df)


      Time           IP    Message  secuence_under_five
0  12:00.0  192.168.1.1    Link up                    1
1  12:01.0  192.168.1.1  Link down                    0
2  12:01.4  192.168.1.2    Link up                    0
3  12:01.6  192.168.1.1    Link up                    0
```

Comment: I think you dont do the check for Link up, link down and link up, as I asked in the question

Comment: Sorry I don't understand well. Please check now

Comment: the logic of pattern values does not take into consideration the 5min time, for eg, I changed my DF to the following and it still shows as "sequence_under_five" = 1 which is wrong,

Comment: df=pd.DataFrame({'Time':['12:00.0','12:06.0','12:01.4','12:12.6'],
                 'IP':'192.168.1.1 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1'.split(),
                  'Message':['Link up','Link down','Link up','Link up']})